# Postgres recursive building of CTE with array values

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have an array of strings which represents function names. I need to iterate through them in order to call each function. They different rows based on the criteria matching against other tables in the function. I need the cumulative rows for a separate query and was thinking that a recursive CTE would be the way to go. However, I am unable to increment the number referencing the index of the array. Any advice? Also, if this is just a bad approach, any tips would be great :D

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name(target_table TEXT, identifier INT) returns setof table_name as
$$
DECLARE
 function_names text[];
BEGIN
  function_names := '{fn1, fn2, fn3}';
  WITH RECURSIVE non_matches(n) as (
    SELECT * FROM non_matching_records($1, $2, function_names[1])
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM non_match_records($1, $2, function_names[n+1] 
      WHERE n < ARRAY_LENGTH(function_names, 1) + 1
  )
  SELECT * FROM non_matches;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**EDIT:** Removed reference to same table return. I forgot that's why I'm taking in the table argument so it can return void. I need the collection of records returned from each function to be able to run another query on them.

**UPDATE:**

Here's where I'm at with my recursive query atm:

```
WITH RECURSIVE non_matches AS (
        SELECT *, 1 AS depth FROM non_matching_records($1, $2, function_names[1])
        UNION
        SELECT c.*, nm.depth + 1 AS depth FROM non_matching_records($1, $2, function_names[nm.depth]) c, non_matches nm
    )
    SELECT * FROM non_matches;
```

The error I receive from this update is no column called `depth` If I don't include the CTE name. And no entry for CTE if I use it. Not really sure how to access that in the brackets to access the array.

`non_matching_records` is a function that find the non matching records.

Comment: Have you tried to get the index using a window function? Try this code: `WITH j AS (
  SELECT unnest('{fn1, fn2, fn3}'::TEXT[]) AS f
  ) SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY 1)-1 AS idx, f FROM j` (index starting in `0`)

Comment: I have not, will try now :D

Comment: Alright. Let me know if it helps... it's a bit hard to test without your environment :) Another option would be something like this: `SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY 1)-1 AS idx, f 
FROM (SELECT unnest('{fn1, fn2, fn3}'::TEXT[]) AS f) AS j`

Comment: @JimJones I wasn't able to get this work. I guess I'm not sure you're vision for the implementation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it late last night. Turns out, once I added the `depth` column, I was selecting *from* the wrong 'table' initially. I switched the order of the tables, having the cte first and *then* joining with the function that returns the records. This gave me access to the depth column and allowed me to increment the index

```
WITH RECURSIVE non_matches AS (
        SELECT c.*, 1 AS depth FROM non_matching_records($1, $2, function_names[1]) c
        UNION
        SELECT c.*, nm.depth + 1 as depth 
        FROM non_matches nm, non_matching_records($1, $2, function_names[nm.depth]) c
        WHERE nm.depth < array_length(match_rules, 1) + 1
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just loop over the array and use `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` to call each function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name(target_table regclass, identifier INT) returns setof table_name AS
$$
DECLARE 
  function_names regproc[] := '{fn1, fn2, fn3}';
  fn regproc;
BEGIN
  FOREACH fn IN ARRAY function_names
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %s(%s, %L)', fn, $1, $2);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I have used regclass and regproc here to help with schema-qualifying the tables and functions, but you could change them back to text as long as you are careful about how these are called.

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, I fixed my question. I forgot why I was taking in the table name as an argument. because I need to be able to access all of the records found and insert into a few different tables in a different schema. And the return table would be different based on the inputed table name :( Sorry about that. But thank you for the regclass and regproc. I had no idea about those. I'm all about trying to make things safer :D